# Regex for "NR###" and "D########"

Tags: regex

Looking to find a regex for the following:

1. Two uppercase letters (must be letter "N" followed by "R"), immediately followed by 3 numbers (and only 3 numbers).
   EX: NR100, or NR531, etc..

   - I currently have [NR]{2}\d{3} but allows, A. lower case "nr" and 3 or more numbers.
2. An uppercase "D" followed by exactly 8 numbers (numbers in any order). 
   EX: D12345678

   - I currently have [D]{1}\d{8} but allows, A. lower case "d" and 8 or more numbers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a regex-writing service.

Comment: You are using sets in your regex, `[NR]` means `N`, or `R` (the order is not important). You want `NR\d{3}`.

Comment: `NR\d{3}` and `D\d{8}` should do the job just fine. Turn off case insensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

```
NR\d{3}(?!\d)
```

You can add a negative lookahead `(?!\d)` to forbid matching strings that have more than 3 digits in a row.  If you don't want to match `nr`, make sure the 'ignore case' option is turned OFF in your programming language.

The same concept would apply to your 'D' problem.